# Include fields of array type with dim > 1 in generated equals and hashCode?

Tags: intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4, is there a way to make it possible for the `equals`- and `hashCode`-method generator (accessed via Alt + Insert) to use fields of array types with dimension larger than one ?

EDIT: Below are two screenshots. When the dimension of the array is > 1 the field show up unchecked and cannot be checked, while when it is = 1 it is in the list and automatically checked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can manully pick which fields are used each time ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky Nope. When I have a field of type eg. int[][] it is not possible to check it in the list of fields that the generated equals method will use. If I change to an int[] then it is automatically checked when the list shows up.